# Hide Chatter in Home Page after Summer 15

Tags: chatter, home-page-component

Salesforce is phasing out the use of arbitrary HTML on Home Page Components.  I have used CSS or JS solutions to hide the Chatter Feed from within a HTML Home Page Component.  This allows a more completely customized Home Page solution.  ([Especially elegant using Skuid to customize the page](http://help.skuidify.com/m/supercharge-your-ui/l/117747-reclaim-the-salesforce-home-page))

After Summer15 the only available component for customizing the home page will be a VF page - that will be nested in an iFrame.  This makes it impossible to include code that affects the rest of the page - like the chatter feed.

Any ideas on retaining this capability?